# The space between last 2 elements are bigger than the first 2 elements, although they have the same css

Tags: html, space

I got a weird outcome with my webpage. I want to have the menu in the middle with
some space between them, I still have to figure that out.

But what is weird is how can it be that there is more space between **what-how and how-quiz** and less space between **Why-what**

```
https: //plnkr.co/edit/txRQ0X9wTKhCPFIcbv3R?p=preview
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you have an invisible white space between the two. Apparently that is caused because of the line-break (the first two elements are written in the same line but then latter two aren't) although that shouldn't happen. I had the same problem once.

Writing all of them in the same line should fix the problem, I don't know any better solution.

Comment: Yea, what u were saying was right. When I put the code (or a bit of the code) next to each other the white space is gone ( or comes back, how you put it). Weird problem but it helps ! Thanks !!